# Android. PreferenceActivity. ListPreference. Как изменить цвет бэкграунда у ListPreference

Tags: android, color, android-preferences, background

Реализую "ночную тему". 
Не понимаю как изменить цвет бэкграунда у ListPreference

PreferenceActivity дневная тема:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

PreferenceActivity ночная тема:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как видите, только цвет заголовка подцепился из "ночных" цветов.

Использую следующую тему:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/primary_text</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/secondary_text</item>
    <item name="toolbarStyle">@style/Toolbar</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/background_window</item>
    <item name="preferenceTheme">@style/PreferenceThemeOverlay.v14.Material</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/icons</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.Settings" parent="AppTheme" />
```

Какие параметры отвечают за:

1. Бэкграунд ListPreference;
2. Цвет текста пунктов ListPreference;
3. Цвет "переключателей" ListPreference - хочу заменить на "accent" цвет (в моем случае оранжевый).

Спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ответ найден - это косяк стандартного Android Studio эмулятора.
Genimotion и все "железячки" отображают как надо.

Использую тему выше
И файл описания ресурсов-цветов в папке "values-night"

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте эти атрибуты:

```
<item name="android:textColor">@android:color/black</item>

<item name="android:textColorAlertDialogListItem">@android:color/black</item>

<item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
```

И ещё попробуйте переопределить стиль диалога:

```
<item name="android:dialogTheme">@style/MyDialogStyle</item>
<item name="android:alertDialogTheme">@style/MyDialogStyle</item>

<style name="MyDialogStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/material_indigo_500</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/black</item>
    <item name="android:textColorAlertDialogListItem">@android:color/black</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```